# WinForm looks different than in VS designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resolution

The WinForm I'm building looks like the left one in VS, and the right one if I debug or build/run it:
[image]

Note the toolstripbuttons, form icon, text, everything.
I'm using VS Community 2015, my screen is full HD (1920x1080), not that it should matter.
Any clue on how shall I manage to get the same quality as in VS?

Comment: [Application.EnableVisualStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.100).aspx) missing?

Comment: @Steve Nope. It must  be something else.

Comment: It seems dpi-awareness problem. You may find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33588482/3110834) helpful.