# WinForm DPI issue

Tags: c#, winforms, dpi

There was this issue:

[WinForm looks different than in VS designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745213/winform-looks-different-than-in-vs-designer)

I thought I solved with this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/1806838

I used the `app.manifest` one.

```
<dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
```

After that all seemed to be OK. It looks perfect if I debug or if I run the application from the folder where I build it. (`app\app\bin\Release\app.exe`). But if I copy the executable outside that folder (for e.g. to my Desktop, and I run it then it looks like this (the right one obviously):
[image]

It's like the `app.manifest` is not embedded, but I checked the settings and it seems to be OK. Also, I made sure that in the app properties the correct manifest file is being selected.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** So, it seems if the `app.exe.manifest` is in the same folder then it looks good, otherwise it's not.

**EDIT2:** I found that I have 2 `app.mainfest` files. One is `app\app\app.manifest` and the other one is `app\app\Properties\app.manifest`. So I deleted both and added a very new one having the DPI setting in it. I still have the same issue. Checked the `app.manifest` properties and the `Build Action` is set to `None`. Shall I change it?

**EDIT3:** I addedd `app.manifest` to the `Resources` and set app -> Properties -> Manifest to be `Resources\app.manifest`. Still the same.

Comment: Curious. If you copy that folder to the desktop and then run the exe, does it work?  Perhaps there's a file in that folder that is silently helping out.

Comment: @MillieSmith Correct. This is the case. And there is a file called `app.exe.manifest` which is suspicious.

Comment: But no. I copied only the exe and the exe.manifest. But apparently that's not enough.

Comment: Hmm... do a binary search with the files. Keep removing half of them :D.

Comment: @MillieSmith OK, I tried with the wrong exe... Sorry. So yes, `app.exe.manifest` is the one. So if it is not in the same folder, then it looks awful.

Comment: I'm going to fall asleep... it's really late... but try to embed the manifest file in the exe somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after trying to compile the `app.manifest` for 3 days, I added another setting to see whether it's going to be applied. This was the run as admin:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

And when I tried to build with that I got an error message stating that it's not compatible with `ClickOnce`. And this was the point when I realized what a moron I am. After disabling `ClickOnce` via `app` -> `Properties` -> `Security` -> uncheck `Enable ClickOnce security settings` everything is just working perfectly. It seems that if it's enabled then it ignores the manifest.

I'm really sorry for the time of people tried to help wasted.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Don't worry about the time. That's part of programming.

Comment: @MillieSmith I know, it's just sometimes frustrating when you are on the wrong path for long time. Anyway, thank you for your help, it is really appreciated.