# C# Winform Control Dimensions Strange Out Of Editor?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I've run into this weird sizing issue for my windows form application when run. Now in the designer the program looks like This1 (can't upload more then 2 links so look in comments). However when I run it from visual studio it looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3vWm.png) (notice how all the controls are closer together, the picture box is automatically wider and taller & the picturebox in tileset subform is larger).

When built and run outside of Visual Studio from the `bin\debug` folder, it looks perfectly fine (as it would in Visual Studio like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkTjf.png)). However I recently changed the build folder to one with a shorter path and when I now run from there the entire form looks much larger and the picturebox is again scaled in this2 (can't upload more then 2 links so look in comments).

Comment: This1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAnwg.png

Comment: This2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4rk5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745213/winform-looks-different-than-in-vs-designer).

- Did you try to set the dpi awareness in the manifest as in the question above?
- Also be sure, you run both (visual studio) and the .exe from
  bin/debug as the same user (ex. run as Administrator).

And if it's not to late, consider a change to wpf, it responds much better to the different screens and different resolutions - at least in my opinion and experience.

Comment: Yeah it's too late; I've written far too much to port over any time soon. thnx for the advice though.

Comment: Thnx that fixed it :)