# How to set the dpiaware in the cs file

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the windows form application in this the image is blurry for high resolution monitors.on adding the dpiaware to true in app.manifest file the image is rendering fine.Can any one please provide the solution for adding the DPIaware to true in the cs file with out using manifest file.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33588241/3110834).

Comment: Hi Thank you for your update,it is working fine.In WPF application the image becomes blurry in low zoomvalue(0.5).Can you please provide any solution for this.