# Table control alignment issue in winforms rdlc

Tags: winforms, rdlc

I am trying to render rdlc in winforms with

```
Me.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
```

I am getting table control alignment issue when rendering

[image]

but when printing it is displaying properly
[image]

below is the code I am using for render rdlc in winforms

```
Me.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local

        Dim LocalReport = Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport
        LocalReport.Refresh()

        LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\MessageReports\\Report2.rdlc"

        Dim dsReportDataSource = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource()
        dsReportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1"
        dsReportDataSource.Value = dtCancelMessage

        LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dsReportDataSource)

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

I am using using dotnet framework 4.8
Is this the known issue or am I doing anything wrong

Comment: Maybe it's something about DPI. Did you try to add a manifest to the app and enable dpiaware?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Sorry I am new to rdlc. What is manifest and how to add that to app?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588482/3110834) to make your application [dpi aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#dpiaware)

Comment: Thanks it really worked.