# Report get shrink when user choose 125% or 150% for the OS font size?

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

In my windows-form-application I have reports that are set on A4 page and working perfectly and printing on full page but when user changes OS `font-size` from 100% to 125% or 150%, the print layout get shrink in the application. how to make the report constant for every OS `font-size`.

here is the print-preview after changing OS Font-Size.[image: Print-Layout after changing OS Font-Size]

Comment: Have you tried enabling DPI awareness [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588482/3110834)?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've tried it but it is messing with all forms rather than solving my issue of report.

Comment: I cannot imagine how it's making a mess in all the forms, but it basically is something that  all applications are supposed to support.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Whatever, but it is not working on report.